# Saving python Rtree spatial index to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rtree

I would like to save an Rtree spatial index to file. I tried using pickle.dump, but when I loaded the .p file using pickle.load, the bounds were way off. Here's an example:

```
import rtree, pickle
from rtree import index
iidx=index.Index()
iidx.add(0,(1,2,3,4))
f=open('rtree2.p','wb')
pickle.dump(iidx,f)
f.close()
```

When I try opening the file:

```
f=open('rtree2.p','rb')
uudx=pickle.load(f)
f.close()
uudx.get_bounds()
```

I get:

```
[1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308]
```

Comment: The Rtree documentation appears to use dumps and loads, which writes the index as a string

Comment: I think the dumps and loads are just for serializing Python objects for storage in the index. I don't think you can pickle the index object since it's just a ctypes wrapper around libspatialindex.

Comment: @marc-pfister I did this on a test index, and the shape of the index seems to have changed. The original index I used had two index nodes each with leaves. I "saved" this to file using your `insert` method, and reloaded it, but the new index has just one index node with all the leaves in that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the built-in disk serialization an acceptable solution?

*Make an index and flush it to disk:*

```
from rtree.index import Index
idx = Index('filename')
idx.insert(0, (1, 2, 3, 4))
idx.get_bounds()
# [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
idx.close()
```

*Load the index at a later point in time:*

```
from rtree.index import Index
idx = Index('filename')
idx.get_bounds()
# [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this approach, but I'm seeing the same issue as the OP.